# Get Data from a List of Firestore DocumentReferences to State React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I have a list of Firebase DocumentReferences and I need to get the data and set state with that data.

This is what i tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
      let x = [];
      roomData.players.forEach(
        async (playerRef: FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentReference) => {
          const playerSnap = await playerRef.get()
          x.push(playerSnap.data())
        }
      );
      setPlayers(x)
```

The list has 2 items.
The state is being set 3 times. Once normally with 2 objects. Second time it's set to an empty array and 3 with only one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you left out the critical part, which is the second parameter of useEffect, which determines when setPlayers get called.

Secondly, the async code probably doesn't run as you expect, since the content of x when it's passed to setPlayers is not synchronized. You cannot use async in forEach, as there is no way to await all results. So in this case, `setPlayers(x)` may be called before `x.push(playerSnap.data())`.

So the simplest change is to rewrite the useEffect first parameter as

```js
roomData.players.forEach(
  async (playerRef: FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentReference) => {
    const playerSnap = await playerRef.get();
    setPlayers(prevPlayers => [...prevPlayers, playerSnap]);
  }
);
```

This updates players asynchronously.

If you need players to update synchronously, for example to update the UI only once, or to reflect the order of players as in Firestore, forEach must be replaced. One such way is to use a simple for loop to sequentially get. Another way is to construct an array of promise and feed it to `Promise.all`.